# Uninstall mongoDB from ubuntu

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

I have installed MongoDB 3.0.1 following the commands in [Install MongoDB Community Edition on Ubuntu](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/) on my ubuntu 14.04 64 bit system and I installed [Robomongo](https://robomongo.org/) interface to use that.

When I try to connect MongoDB using Robomongo I get an error that authorization failed. I found [Add support for SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication (MongoDB 3.0+)](https://github.com/paralect/robomongo/issues/766) which explains that Robomongo 0.8.5 doesn't support MongoDB 3.0.X fully.

In response, I want to remove MongoDB 3.0.1 and install MongoDB 2.2.

I tried the following commands:

```
 apt-get remove --purge mongodb
```

and also

```
apt-get autoremove --purge mongodb
```

In both cases I got the following error:

> " Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
>   E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?"

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have access `sudo` privileges? If so, `sudo apt-get remove --purge mongodb`

Comment: Try to run this commands from root.
`sudo apt-get remove --purge mongodb`

Comment: Adding sudo worked. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if it was a typo or not, but don't use MongoDB 2.2, it's very old at this point.  The previous release to 3.0 (2.6) should work fine with robomongo

Answer (score 191):

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

this worked for me

Comment: make sure to remove mongodb-server if you're into replica sets.

Comment: I used this to remove the packages:
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-*

Comment: This for me didn't remove the mongodb.conf file...
after this I executed the commands from Kevin's answer

Answer (score 111):

In my case `mongodb` packages are named `mongodb-org` and `mongodb-org-*`

So when I type `sudo apt purge mongo` then `tab` (for auto-completion) I can see all installed packages that start with `mongo`.

Another option is to run the following command (which will list all packages that contain `mongo` in their names or their descriptions):

```
dpkg -l | grep mongo
```

In summary, I would do (to purge all packages that start with `mongo`):

```
sudo apt purge mongo*
```

and then (to make sure that no mongo packages are left):

```
dpkg -l | grep mongo
```

Of course, as mentioned by @alicanozkara, you will need to manually remove some directories like `/var/log/mongodb` and `/var/lib/mongodb`

Running the following `find` commands:

`sudo find /etc/ -name "*mongo*"` and `sudo find /var/ -name "*mongo*"`

may also show some files that you may want to remove, like:

```
/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.2.list
```

and:

```
/var/lib/apt/lists/repo.mongodb.*
```

You may also want to remove user and group `mongodb`, to do so you need to run:

```
sudo userdel -r mongodb
sudo groupdel mongodb
```

To check whether `mongodb` user/group exists or not, try:

```
cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd | grep mongo
cut -d: -f1 /etc/group | grep mongo
```

Comment: Even after all the steps and referring to almost all the answers on most of the sites, I was not being able to find my issue. 
Even after all the purging, when I ran mongod, it ran.

Then I did: sudo find / -name "*mongo*"
Then I removed by:-

sudo rm -R /usr/local/bin/mongo*
sudo rm -R /usr/bin/mongo*

Comment: @AkashDeepSinghal Try removing the mongo files in /usr/bin. I don't know why no one mentions this here.

Answer (score 80):

I suggest the following to make sure everything is uninstalled:

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-clients mongodb-server mongodb-dev

sudo apt-get purge mongodb-10gen

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

This should also remove your config from

```
 /etc/mongodb.conf.
```

If you want to clean up completely and you might also want to remove the data directory

`/var/lib/mongodb`

Comment: I would just add that if the commands above are not working, run 'apt list --installed' to find the exact name of the Mongo packages you have installed, then execute the commands Kevin has outlined with the correct names.

Answer (score 44):

use command with sudo,

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge mongodb
```

OR

```
sudo apt-get remove mongodb* --purge
```

It will remove complete mongodb

Comment: Note in 2021 the second command above works but the first one tends to fail on modern installs.

Comment: the second one is using outdated apt patterns, that wildcard may not work. instead you'd want to do remove '^mongodb*' https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/man7/apt-patterns.7.html

Answer (score 31):

Stop MongoDB

Stop the mongod process by issuing the following command:

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Remove Packages

Remove any MongoDB packages that you had previously installed.

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Remove Data Directories.

Remove MongoDB databases and log files.

```
 sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
```

Answer (score 17):

Sometimes this works;

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org --fix-missing --fix-broken
sudo apt-get autoremove mongodb-org --fix-missing --fix-broken
```

Comment: Worked for me with Linux Mint 18 and mongodb 3.2.10

Answer (score 4):

use **sudo** with the command:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mongodb  
apt-get autoremove --purge mongodb
```

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove MongoDB completely from your System, use following steps.

1. `sudo service mongod stop`
2. `sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*`
3. `sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb`
4. `sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb`