# Mongodb stop working: Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: linux, mongodb, unix, server, ubuntu-14.04

After restarting the server, MongoDB, stopped working.

When I start `service mongod start` and gives the default message: `mongodb start/running, process 6986`

But it so soon after, does not give error messages and even saved log.

And when I start which wants executable: `mongo / mongod / mongorestore / etc ..`

it gives the following message:

```
Attempt to add global initializer failed, status: DuplicateKey ForkServer
Aborted (core dumped)
```

I'm using `MongoDB 3.2` on `Ubuntu 14.04.2`

I've reinstalled the MongoDB already made a downgrade and keep getting the same message.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are duplicate keys in your data when you try to restore them?

Comment: No, I get this error even pointing to a new directory. I really do not know what to do. I'm almost formatting the server and reconfigure everything.

Comment: In my case it was incompatible version of `mongod`. I've upgraded from `4.0` to `4.4` but it was a must-do to first upgrade to `4.2`. To figure this out I started the server with increased verbosity `mongod -vvvv --config /etc/mongod.conf` and one of the error messages pointed me that my current server binary version is incompatible with the existing database files.

Answer (score 7):

I ended up having this same problem. I received the error message `mongodb.service: Failed with result 'core-dump'.`
To fix it, you should run:

```
sudo mongod --repair --dbpath /path/to/mongodb
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this error on last version, that now is 5.
I installed old 4.4 version, and all works perfect.

Answer (score 0):

To troubleshoot this problem you have to uninstall and completely remove all files related to MongoDB by using [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51231162/11742605)

and then run one by one

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install mongodb
sudo systemctl status mongodb
```

That's it this steps are working for me