# uninstall mongodb 3.4.4 from ubuntu 14

Tags: mongodb

How to uninstall mongodb v3.4.4 completely from my system ubuntu 14.

found [Uninstall mongoDB from ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554521/uninstall-mongodb-from-ubuntu)
But not sure if it works on v 3.4.4

Comment: Have you tried to uninstall it as described? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: no i did not tried, as my system is in production so i afraid

Answer (score 2):

First Stop MongoDB Service if Available

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

Remove MongoDB Packages

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
```

Remove Data Directories

```
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb
sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
```

If your Custom Define Database and log path than u manually remove as above.
Hope this may solve your issue