# How to remove mongodb on WSL ubuntu 18.04

Tags: mongodb, uninstallation

I have a [mongodb](/questions/tagged/mongodb) version `4.0`, but I want to upgrade it into version `4.2`. When I tried to upgrade it and checked the version it's still showing `4.0`. Now I'm trying to remove it first, then install the version `4.2`, but the problem now is I cannot remove it.

I tried removing it by deleting the folder `data` I'm using for mongodb and the `mongod` in the root.

I have tried some uninstall/remove script

```
sudo service mongod stop
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org*
sudo rm -r /var/log/mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
apt-get remove --purge mongodb
apt-get autoremove --purge mongodb
```

I almost tried all the uninstall script but with no luck. I know some of you already encountered this situation and be able to enlightened me of what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These scripts fixed the problem for me, got it from another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554521/uninstall-mongodb-from-ubuntu#answer-39875403)

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org --fix-missing --fix-broken
sudo apt-get autoremove mongodb-org --fix-missing --fix-broken
```